# Swift, How to Parse/Decode the JSON using Decodable and Codable, When key are unknow/dynamic

Tags: json, swift, parsing, codable, decodable

Below is my JSON, and I am not able to decode(using CodingKeys) 
The data within the **regions** key is a Dictionary ("IN-WB", "IN-DL" & so on....), as the keys are dynamic, it can be changed more or less.

Please help me parsing the same using Decodable and Codable.

**All the data should be within the single model.**

```
{
            "provider_code": "AIIN",
            "name": "Jio India",
            "regions": [
                {
                    "IN-WB": "West Bengal"
                },
                {
                    "IN-DL": "Delhi NCR"
                },
                {
                    "IN-TN": "Tamil Nadu"
                },
                {
                    "IN": "India"
                }
            ]
        }
```

Comment: Are you responsible for the JSON? Consider that an array of dictionaries containing only one key-value pair respectively is a very inefficient model. Better send a dictionary like `{ "code" :  "IN-WB", "name" : "West Bengal"}` this solves your issue by the way.

Comment: What you mean by 'All the data should be within the single model.' ?)

Answer (score 2):

Just use a Dictionary for the regions.

```
struct Locations: Codable {
    let providerCode: String
    let name: String
    let regions: [[String: String]]

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case providerCode = "provider_code"
        case name, regions
    }
}
```

You cannot create a specific model for the regions as you wont know the property names

Comment: But you can create Region(id, name). Why not, by decoder.unkeyedContainer() or dynamic key.

Comment: you dont know the JSON key? so JSONDecoder wont be able to do it, you would need to override `init(decoder:_)` to parse as `[[String: String]]`, loop each item found and init a region like `Region(key, value)`

Answer (score 0):

One of possible approach, without using dictionary. But still we have to found key at first )

I like this style as we can use Regions from beginning.

```
// example data.
let string = "{\"provider_code\":\"AIIN\",\"name\":\"Jio India\",\"regions\":[{\"IN-WB\":\"West Bengal\"},{\"IN-DL\":\"Delhi NCR\"},{\"IN-TN\":\"Tamil Nadu\"},{\"IN\":\"India\"}]}"
let data   = string.data(using: .utf8)!

// little helper
struct DynamicGlobalKey: CodingKey {
    var stringValue: String
    init?(stringValue: String) {
        self.stringValue = stringValue
    }

    var intValue: Int? { return nil }
    init?(intValue: Int) { return nil }
}

// model
struct Location: Decodable {
    let providerCode: String
    let name: String
    let regions: [Region]
}

extension Location {
    struct Region: Decodable {
        let key:  String
        let name: String

        init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
            let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: DynamicGlobalKey.self)
            key  = container.allKeys.first!.stringValue
            name = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: container.allKeys.first!)
        }
    }
}

// example of decoding.
let decoder = JSONDecoder()
decoder.keyDecodingStrategy = .convertFromSnakeCase

let location = try decoder.decode(Location.self, from: data)
```